# Visual Studio designer with ApplicationContext instead of a MainForm

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2013

VisualStudio 2013, C++/CLI.

I'm working on a "background" app and its root interface is a `NotifyIcon` with a menu attached. I don't have a `MainForm` and do the hide trick, instead I have what equates to: `Application::Run(gcnew ApplicationContext());`. To get the `NotifyIcon, ContextMenuStrip, ToolStripMenuItems`, I just wrote that code to tied them together and that all works fine.

My question is: Is there a way to either 1) get the designer to recognize this control and allow me to use the designer to modify it? Or, 2) Is there a way I can start fresh with the designer and add controls to an `ApplicationContext`?

To get started with the Designer I've got to go to `Add | New Item | ??`. With the `??` being a Windows Form or, the closest to what I want, a `UserControl` but it seems like a long way around to what I want to do. Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: It is possible, Project + Add New Item > Code > Component Class.  That gives you a design surface on which you can drop a NotifyIcon and a ContextMenuStrip.   You can create an instance of it in your main() method.  It is however pretty clumsy and several tweaks are needed, don't throw away what you have.

Comment: Yep, that was exactly what I needed! Thanks. I didn't know "Component Class" would drop me in to the designer that way. Cool - thanks a lot. I was able to add the items exactly the way I wanted to.